# How do I display tooltips in a Python FMX GUI app?

Tags: python, user-interface, tooltip, firemonkey

I have created a window `Form` with a `Button` on it with the [DelphiFMX GUI library for Python](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python). I want to be able to add a hover tooltip to the button which explains what it does. Here's an example of a button tooltip on a Form, when I hover on it with my mouse, then it shows "I am a button":

[image: Form with Button and tooltip]

Here's the code I currently have to create my Form with Button:

```
from delphifmx import *

class frmMain(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Caption = 'My Form'
        self.Width = 1000
        self.Height = 500
        self.Position = "ScreenCenter"

        self.myButton = Button(self)
        self.myButton.Parent = self
        self.myButton.Text = "Hello World!"
        self.myButton.Align = "Client"
        self.myButton.Margins.Top = 20
        self.myButton.Margins.Right = 20
        self.myButton.Margins.Bottom = 20
        self.myButton.Margins.Left = 20
        self.myButton.StyledSettings = ""
        self.myButton.TextSettings.Font.Size = 50
        self.myButton.onClick = self.Button_OnClick

    def Button_OnClick(self, sender):
        print("Hello World!")

def main():
    Application.Initialize()
    Application.Title = "My Application"
    Application.MainForm = frmMain(Application)
    Application.MainForm.Show()
    Application.Run()
    Application.MainForm.Destroy()

main()
```

I tried doing `self.myButton.toolTip = "Click me!"`, but this doesn't work.

How do tooltips work in the DelphiFMX library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tooltips` in DelphiFMX are called `Hints`. Here's how you would add a Hint to your button:

```
self.myButton.Hint = "Click me!"
self.myButton.ShowHint = True
```

Here's a screenshot of that exact code that shows the "Click me!" tooltip/hint when I hovered on it:
[image: Python GUI Hello World with Button Tooltip]

You simply use the `Hint` property to add your string and then set `ShowHint` to True.

You can also do multi-line hints by adding `chr(13) + chr(10)` to your Hint string:

```
self.myButton.Hint = "Click me!" + chr(13) + chr(10) + "I'm a button!"
self.myButton.ShowHint = True
```

[image: Python GUI Hello World with Button Multi Line Tooltip]